# Python get lost entry from index value

Tags: python

I have a list l, `l = {'item': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], 'color': ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']}`. I found the index for "banana" by `l['item'].index('banana')`. "banana" has an index of 2. How can I get find "apple" in the list by knowing the index number in that specific column?

Comment: Did you mean that because you know that `'apple'` is at index 0 you can print it out using `l['item'][0]`?

Comment: `l` is not a list, it is a dict... dict objects don't have "columns". It isn't exactly clear what you are asking, but I think, given that "apple" has index 0, then you want `l['item'][0]`...

Answer (score 2):

`l['item'][0] == 'apple'`

**Explanation**

```py
type(l) == dict
type(l['item']) == list
l['item'][0] == 'apple'
l['color'][0] == 'red'

print('item: {} has color: {}'.format(l['item'][0], l['color'][0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the information about the fruits as dict of lists:

```
fruits = {'item': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], 'color': ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']}
```

you can get the name and color of any given item by accessing the same index of each.  So to get `'apple'` you access `fruits['item'][0]:

```
>>> fruits['item'][0], fruits['color'][0]
('apple', 'red')
```

Note that it's usually easier to get at related data like this if you group the related parts more closely together.  For example, what if we flipped this from a dict of lists into a list of dicts?

```
fruits_as_dicts = [
    {'item': item, 'color': color} 
    for item in fruits['item'] 
    for color in fruits['color']
]
```

Now all the information about the apple is just `fruits_as_dicts[0]`:

```
>>> fruits_as_dicts[0]
{'item': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}
>>> fruits_as_dicts[0]['item']
'apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your question.

To find `apple` in your list you would have to do: `1["item"][0]`!

Comment: pssst - it's an "L", not the number "1".    `l` > `1`